# ¿Cómo puedo realizar un botón que cumpla dos funciones? PYQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt

Hola estoy tratando de realizar que un mismo boton haga dos funciones distintas pero al momento de modificar o registrar se aplican a los dos por igual.

```
self.ui.btnConfirmarCliente.clicked.connect(self.enviarFormularioRegistro)
        
self.ui.btnConfirmarCliente.clicked.connect(self.enviarFormularioModificar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer que ese botón llame a una función, y que sea esa función la que llame a las dos que quieres. Algo como:

```
self.ui.btnConfirmarCliente.clicked.connect(self.enviarFormularios)
```

Y en esa función:

```
def enviarFormularios():
    self.enviarFormularioRegistro
    self.enviarFormularioModificar
```